# Manual inferring type of (\x y z -> (x y) z)

Tags: haskell, lambda, types

I would like to understand how to get manual to the correct type of this Haskell expression.

```
(\x y z -> (x y) z)
```

In general I understand roughly how to manually determine the correct type, but with lambda expressions I am totally confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a fast way to get the type and a slow way. The slow way is below and does not remove any unnecessary parentheses.

## The fast way (for *this* function)

Let us remember the properties of Haskell functions, namely for

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

Both `f x y` and `(f x) y` are the same, as `a -> b -> c` is `a -> (b -> c)`.

Thus `\x y z -> (x y) z` is the same as `\x y z -> x y z`. Therefore, if `y`'s and `z`'s type where `a` and `b` resp., then `x`'s type is `a -> b -> c`:

```
\x y z -> x y z :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
```

If we named that function, then we would write:

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
f x y z = x y z
```

or even simpler:

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> c
f = id
```

as it is the identify function restrained to a function type. You can add parentheses around `a -> b -> c` in the type to see that, as `a -> b -> c` is `a -> (b -> c)`:

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)
f = id
```

## The "slow" way

Let's start first by giving the lambda a name. This will enable us to use type signatures and continue from there:

```
f = \x y z -> (x y) z
```

Next, we use the regular function syntax instead of the lambda syntax:

```
f :: A -> B -> C -> D
f x y z = (x y) z
```

Now, we need to figure out `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Due to `x` being applied to `y`, we notice that `A` must be some function type, e.g. `B -> ...?`. Next we notice that `x y` must also be a function. Therefore, `A` needs to be `B -> G`, and `G` needs to be a function again. Since `G` is able to use `z` and therefore a value of type `C`, we know that `G` is `G = C -> D`:

```
f :: (B -> (C -> D)) -> B -> C -> D
```

We now have `x`'s type, it's `B -> (C -> D)`. Since neither `y` nor `z` are restrained, we can now change all type placeholders into type varialbles and end up with:

```
f :: (b -> (c -> d)) -> b -> c -> d
f x y z = (x y) z
```

For a last step, let's rename those variables:

```
f :: (a -> (b -> c)) -> a -> b -> c
f x y z = (x y) z
```

And that's `\x y z -> (x y) z`'s type: `(a -> (b -> c)) -> a -> b -> c`.

Comment: It might be useful to mention that some of these parentheses are redundant.

Comment: @Noughtmare good point. Has been a while since I've used and answered Haskell (questions).